# Dynamically display packet time in scapy

Tags: python, for-loop, scapy

So I have this script:

```
packets = sniff(iface="eth0", filter="tcp and(port 80)", prn=lambda x: x.show())
for pkt in packets:
    print  pkt.show2()
    print  pkt.time
```

The problem is that the script does not cannot give me the time of the packet until I stop sniffing (which then only the last packet time is displayed).

How do I get it to print the time of the packet dynamically while sniffing is still on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that does what you want -

```
def pktinfo(x):
    x.show()
    x.show2()
    print x.time
```

Use that function for the `prn` argument.

```
packets = sniff(iface="eth0", filter="tcp and(port 80)", prn=pktinfo)
```

With `prn` any returned data will be printed. You may want to try building a custom formatted string with the data you want to have displayed and returning it instead of printing it in the function.